# Typesetting "et al" in italics with natbib

Tags: reference, latex, pdflatex, bibtex, biblatex

It looks I'm dealing with an entient problem here but I seem not to find a solution. I'm using Jabref and LaTex(natbib) and I want my reference to appear like this in the text: Peter *et al.*(2023) i.e, with an italic *et al*. #Italic "et al".

I've tried everything, this is potentially my last hope.

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if not supported by default, you can **customize the bibliography style file**

Modify appropriately the `.bst` file to ensure

```
\emph{et al.}
```

[image]

Here is a [fully working example on GitHub](https://github.com/maciejskorski/Customized_Natbib) which you can fork and test under your Overleaf account.

Credits to the LaTex forum
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64149/emphasizing-et-al

Comment: There's [an easier solution using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352119/42). The advantage of this solution is that you don't need to copy and modfiy the .bst file. You can customise the display inside your main LaTeX document.

Comment: I answer the question about natbib and demonstrate how to customize, which adds the value on its own. Of course, we can possibly find tools that support this particular feature.

Comment: I wasn't criticising your answer.

Comment: Didn't suggest that, just wanted to refocus on the constrained setup use-case (e.g. proceedings packages). Thanks for mentioning biblatex, I learned something new :-)